# how to sum decimal values in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working on an sql queries where i have a temp table named

```
 DECLARE @tcal table(TagIndex smallint,TagName nvarchar(20),Total decimal(18,2))
```

in which decimal numbers are used to stored. The values coming are:

```
284.45
233.97
240.17
81.39
67.55
0.00
71.57
72.91
```

I used to sum all the above decimal number by using following query:

```
select  sum(CAST(Total AS decimal(18,2)))  FROM @tcal where TagIndex>44
```

The sum coming after the query is :-

```
767.56
```

But the actual result should be:

```
1052.01
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Your query has `where TagIndex>44`.  Are there rows on your table where TagIndex<=44?

Comment: Why are you casting `Total`?

Comment: yes there are 52 rows. I want to sum first 1 to 44 and then in second 45 to 52. Here i am showing data of 45 to 52.

Comment: The values is being stored in a temp table @tcal and Total is a column in that temp table.

Comment: What should the final result look like? Update your question.

Comment: The `cast` is useless. `sum(total)` should work just fine

Comment: i used that also but not giving desired result

Comment: Works just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=abb19f2be3401407d2b5f598c5f9616c

Comment: The difference between the (expected) `1052.01` and (the alleged) `767.56` is exactly `284.45`. The `WHERE` clause or the `TagIndex` values are likely not exactly what you say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it's not an answer, just a better-formated comment because you are wrong in some way, I have written the below example.

```
DECLARE @tcal table(TagIndex smallint,TagName nvarchar(20),Total decimal(18,2)) ;

insert into @tcal
values
 (45,null,284.45)
,(45,null,233.97)
,(45,null,240.17)
,(45,null,81.39)
,(45,null,67.55)
,(45,null,0.00)
,(45,null,71.57)
,(45,null,72.91) ;

select  sum(CAST(Total AS decimal(18,2)))  FROM @tcal where TagIndex>44 ;
select  sum(Total)  FROM @tcal where TagIndex>44 ;
```

and it works. So you are filtering your data wrong or did some mistake.

My guess is your data is missing the first row because it's tag **`= 44`**.

(Remember in SQL > <> >=  =))

Comment: It works fine for me. Thanx

Comment: Can you please tell us what exactly worked fine? Did you have `tagindex = 44` in the row with 284.45?